# How to adjust a value in Xamarin Forms and make it not exceed 360?

Tags: c#, math, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to adjust the value of a double that is 0-360.

This is my code:

```
double testvalue;

testvalue = e.Heading + 90;
```

The problem when I do this is that e.heading has a value of 0-360 degrees. So when i Add + 90 to that and write out testvalue in the log it exceeds 360 deegres.

What I have started with is:

```
if (testvalue > 360)
{

}
```

But I am not sure how I will do the math/logic here to make it work so that my double `thevalue` has a value of 0-360 and does not exceed 360.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do `thevalue = thevalue % 360;`. This makes sense from my perspective as turning 480 degrees is essentially the same as turning 120 degrees.

Comment: Yeah when I try it out and add `testvalue = testvalue % 360;`inside my `if (testvalue > 360)` it seems to work very good!

Comment: @UnoDosCode You actually don't even need the `if` condition.  `50 % 360` is still `50`.

Comment: Ah i understand :) Very nice. Thanks a lot for this